# Jquery selector on prettyphoto effect

Tags: jquery

Im working on a site using a photopretty library plugin, when I click on an image, it add the template code to display image as popup into my side and remove it completely when I close. But I need to add some element into the prettypphoto efect template popup for that specific image. so I work on another script main.js using jquery to select the name inside that template but it does not work.

I mean when I click the image the template code start adding to my side, so I use on click to select its element. does that make sense? please correct me if Im wrong. I can not modify the plugin file.

```
 main.js
 jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
     jQuery('.contact_plan img').click(function(){
        var element = jQuery('.element');
        jQuery('.element').detach();
        jQuery('.pp_content_container').append(element);
     }); 

 });


 The prettyphoto template look like this
 <div class="pp_pic_holder pp_default">
 <div class="pp_top">...</div>
 <div class="pp_content_container">..</div>
 ....
```

Comment: Can you please put up a fiddle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function you can use to check when an element comes into existance :

```
;(function ($, window) {

var intervals = {}; 
var removeListener = function(selector) {

if (intervals[selector]) {

    window.clearInterval(intervals[selector]);
    intervals[selector] = null;
}
};
var found = 'waitUntilExists.found';


$.fn.waitUntilExists = function(handler, shouldRunHandlerOnce, isChild) {

    var selector = this.selector;
    var $this = $(selector);
    var $elements = $this.not(function() { return $(this).data(found); });

    if (handler === 'remove') {

        // Hijack and remove interval immediately if the code requests
        removeListener(selector);
    }
    else {

        // Run the handler on all found elements and mark as found
        $elements.each(handler).data(found, true);

        if (shouldRunHandlerOnce && $this.length) {

            // Element was found, implying the handler already ran for all 
            // matched elements
            removeListener(selector);
        }
        else if (!isChild) {

            // If this is a recurring search or if the target has not yet been 
            // found, create an interval to continue searching for the target
            intervals[selector] = window.setInterval(function () {

                $this.waitUntilExists(handler, shouldRunHandlerOnce, true);
            }, 500);
    }
}

return $this;
};

}(jQuery, window));
```

You can use it like this :

```
$(selector).waitUntilExists(function);
```

**In your case, you can try :**

```
jQuery('.contact_plan img').click(function(){
    var element = jQuery('.element');
    jQuery('.element').detach();
    $('.pp_content_container').waitUntilExists(function(){
        jQuery('.pp_content_container').append(element);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you use

```
jQuery('.pp_content_container').append(element);
 });
```

`append` appends the parameter to the object you're working on.

`appendTo` appends the object you're working on to the parameter.

What you are doing is adding the `$('.pp_content_container')` element to your new element which you haven't (in the given code) added anywhere on the page.

Comment: Hi, thanaks for correct me I will use append, but the problem is that my jquery selector can not get ".pp_content_container", for example I set jQuery('.pp_content_container').css("border","1px solid red"); also does not work

Comment: are you sure the div has been created when you are selecting it ?

Comment: Hi, possibly it has not been created when I am selecting it in my script.js, is there a way to make sure my selector only run after its created?